# What is the GUID in my WP7 application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

If I right click my project and look up "Assembly Information..." in Properties, there is a field called GUID. Should I really care about this, because I have some base code that re re-use and when I just copy and paste the files in a new folder the GUID does not regenerate.

I found one drawback (me thinks) and that's is when you deploy to your phone the old app with the same GUID gets replaces, but thats no show stopper... is there any other things I should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the `WMAppManifest.xml` file and look for the `ProductID` attribute. That is where the GUID for your application resides.

```
<App xmlns="" ProductID="{b57106ca-db22-4809-9311-385c2a5b0921}"...
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `ProductID` in the `WMAppManifest.xml` is only used for development purposes. Once you submit your application to the Market Place it will generate a new `ProductID` and make use of that. This has the handy benefit of allowing you to run the current version of your app from the Market Place and your development version side-by-side on the same phone.

Comment: That's definitely worth mentioning!